# empty field shown in var_dump

Tags: php, html, mysql

i am trying to update the product's all feilds are updating except the one field  that is produt name

below is my var_dump

```
string 'UPDATE product SET

`discription` = 'sasasaas',

`product_name` ='',

category_id = 14,

price=10000,

first_price=1000,

second_price=1000,

third_price=10000,

fourth_price=10000,

total_discount=10000,

product_quantity_discount=10000,

weight=10000,

dimension=1000,

`shipping_class`='sasasas',

stock_quantity=1000,

`stock_status`='inorder',

`back_order`='ALLow'

WHERE product_id = 13' (length=511)
```

my question is that why i am recieving the product_name="" empty ?

this is my code !!

```
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Product Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="product_name" class="form-control" value="<?php   
  echo($row['product_name']);?>">


$this->product_discription = trim ( mysql_prep ( $_POST ['discription'] ) );
    $this->category_id = mysql_prep ( $_POST ['data_category'] );
    $this->regular_price = trim ( mysql_prep ( $_POST ['regular_price'] ) );
    $this->price1 = trim ( mysql_prep ( $_POST ['price1'] ) );
    $this->price2 = trim ( mysql_prep ( $_POST ['price2'] ) );
    $this->price3 = trim ( mysql_prep ( $_POST ['price3'] ) );
    $this->price4 = trim ( mysql_prep ( $_POST ['price4'] ) );
    $this->total_discount = trim ( mysql_prep ( $_POST ['total_discount'] ) );
    $this->product_qantity_discount = trim ( mysql_prep ( $_POST ['quantity_discount'] ) );
    $this->weight = trim ( mysql_prep ( $_POST ['weight'] ) );
    $this->dimension = trim ( mysql_prep ( $_POST ['dimension'] ) );
    $this->shipping_class = trim ( mysql_prep ( $_POST ['shipping'] ) );
    $this->stock_quantity = trim ( mysql_prep ( $_POST ['stock'] ) );
    $this->stock_status = mysql_prep ( $_POST ['stock_status'] );
    $this->back_order = mysql_prep ( $_POST ['back_order'] );
    $this->product_name =  mysql_prep ( $_POST ['product_name'] ) ;
    $this->id = $_GET ['id'];

    $this->sql = "UPDATE product SET

                        `discription` = '{$this->product_discription}',
                        `product_name` ='{$this->product_name}',
                        category_id = {$this->category_id},
                        price={$this->regular_price},
                        first_price={$this->price1},
                        second_price={$this->price2},
                        third_price={$this->price3},
                        fourth_price={$this->price4},
                        total_discount={$this->total_discount},
                        product_quantity_discount={$this->product_qantity_discount},
                        weight={$this->weight},
                        dimension={$this->dimension},
                        shipping_class='{$this->shipping_class}',
                        stock_quantity={$this->stock_quantity},
                        stock_status='{$this->stock_status}',
                        back_order='{$this->back_order}'
                        WHERE product_id = {$this->id}";

      mysql_query($this->sql);
      confirm_query($this->sql);
    echo    var_dump($this->sql ,TRUE);
```

Comment: Apart from the fact you spelt product wrong in $this->produt_name although it appears to be consistent

Comment: What is `var_dump($_POST['product_name'])`?

Comment: string '' (length=0)   empty string !!

Comment: So then your POSTed value is empty (it has nothing to do with MySQL or PHP (unless you're unsetting this value)). Are you sure you're filling it out? Are you sure your field has the correct name? Take a look at your network tab.

Comment: the field the set correct and html is correct evey feild is correct , but i am not getting the product_name field

Comment: What do u get product name after update?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have a typo here:

```
$this->produt_name
```

Comment: string '' (length=0) empty string

Comment: did you check your post data? what's in `$_POST['product_name']`?

Comment: empty field is given in the post data

Comment: are you sure you don't have any other element with the name `product_name` in html form?